# How long should one wait before reposting a question that wasn't answered?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question yesterday, but no one answered it and it only got a dozen views. How long should I have to wait before it is acceptable to post the same question again?

Comment: I think you should edit your question and give further info. Editing your question makes it jump on the top of the list. If you ask a new question, probably it would be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Currently this meta post is one on the hot list, maybe including the link to your question in this meta post can aid giving it further attention.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485396/

Comment: You gave up and posted here after 12 hours?  I've gotten a tumbleweed (no comments or votes and low page views for a week), and then it was answered over a month later.  Sometimes you just need more patience.

Comment: I've earned the [Necromancer Badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) on many sites, many times; occasionally for questions that are years old, some with and some without answers. Ensuring that you have a [good question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is the first step.

Answer (score 39):

Forever. You should never repost a new question which is exactly a duplicate of one of your previous questions. If you do so, you will be flooded with downvotes and your question will be closed very soon.

The best way in this such cases is to modify the question so that it is bumped to the home page, and other users can see it. Edit the question; add more informations to it. Maybe consider editing the title to make your question more attractive and "interesting" to others is also a good option.

You can also offer a bounty for it. Literally every bounty makes the question *much* more attractive.

---

However, I voted to close your question because it literally has nothing to do with TeX or LaTeX. Texstudio issues should be asked in Texstudio bug tracker.  This site is only for, say, issue with compiling with Texstudio, or customize Texstudio so that it accepts `shell-escape`.

Comment: Nice, concise lead.